# What's the best library for manipulating JPEG metadata?

Tags: java, cross-platform, metadata, jpeg, freepascal

I'm after a library that can read and write JPEG image metadata. For example if I wanted to embed and read back a short description or story relating to the jpeg image, in the image file itself, what development library/s would you recommend?

I'm not too fussed about what language (it's a new project), though I've tagged this question for languages I'm familiar with (I'd also consider other languages however). Preferably something that's relatively cross-platform (mac/linux/win), such as Java, FreePascal/Lazarus, C++, Objective-C, etc (to be honest I'm not that familiar with cross-platform, so no idea whether C# is a possibility) - aside from more popular ones such as Java or .NET, it would be preferable for there be no requirement to have any particular framework installed.

Answer (score 6):

try here  http://www.drewnoakes.com/code/exif/

Looks easy to use

Answer (score 1):

[Exif](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) does it all but it is written in Perl.

Answer (score 1):

Perl is cross-platform.

Comment: Yes, but don't you need to install a framework of some sort, at least in Windows? I don't know much about perl, but would be good to learn a new language. Just want to produce something that won't be too much of a hassle to install...

Comment: Well you need to install Perl :) In terms of what Perl module (library) you actually use to do the image manipulation, that's where your cross-platform question needs to be asked. It depends on whether the Perl module you use is pure Perl or depends on a non-Perl library to do the actual work.

Answer (score 1):

[libjpeg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libjpeg) is an excellent library written in C. It can be used to do just about any type of jpeg manipulation. I have successfully compiled it in windows, unix and linux.